# How to Change Response Headers - Pragma & Cache-Control

Tags: apache, debian, apache2, font-awesome, response-headers

I'm using [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in my web application but none of my icons are displaying in Internet Explorer 11.  Per their [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#im-hosting-fonts-on-my-server-and-icons-dont-show-up)
 I learned that this behavior can be tied to the `no-store` Cache-control header, or the `no-cache` Pragma header.

How can I change these header values?

Ideally, there would be some option in the IE developer tools where I can adjust this, but this does not seem possible.  I have been playing around on my web server - Apache 2.4 (Debian) - and attempted the following in my sites-enabled configuration:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|woff|ttf|svg|otf)$">
            <ifModule mod_headers.c>
                    Header unset Cache-Control
                    Header unset Pragma
            </ifModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

I reloaded Apache and no change, these Headers are still set, my icons are still not displayed in Internet Explorer.

I don't have that much experience with Apache, I could really use some help here!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand in the first place why the statement that cache usage is denied should lead to the font not being available in the document. Not being cached does not mean not being available. So why do you think there is a connection?

Comment: @arkascha Per this detail "For Internet Explorer: you don't serve files with no-store option in Cache-control header (Ref: #6454);
For Internet Explorer and HTTPS: you don't serve files with no-cache option in Pragma header."  https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#im-hosting-fonts-on-my-server-and-icons-dont-show-up

Comment: An impressive example of a situation where one has the impression the authors try to avoid any reasoning by purpose. _Why_? Is programming meant to be Voodoo? What you cited is _not_ an explanation, not an answer to my question. It is just a statement without any justification or reasoning. And by the way: I interpret those statements such that you _should_ apply the voodoo trick to specify those no-cache control headers / tags in order to get it working. You seem to try the opposite in your code above.

Comment: @arkascha I wish I could answer your question.  In the absence of understanding why that would be, I was hoping to test it by changing the headers.

Comment: Sure, indeed Xtreme-trying-out-every-arbitrary-combination is often the only way to get something to work in IE. The world will be a better place when it finally is going to be buried. All the web developers will rise and sing and be happy.

Comment: What is your recommendation?  Know more?  I'm trying to...

Comment: No, unfortunately I have no recommendation, sorry. That is what I actually tried to express: shrugging my shoulders. This is Microsoft and Internet Explorer. Unfortunately it looks as if their new torture tool "Edge" is getting shaped even worse.

Comment: OK, well I appreciate your reading my question and providing some feedback.

Comment: Now that I think about it I indeed remember a similar issue I had to deal with some 2 weeks ago. Something with typesquare font integration, so Japanese fonts. MS-IE 11 had an issue that looks similar to this: it appeared to send a HEAD request, get's back a "not modified" header (http 304) and consequently does not fire the full GET request. But since it does not find a cached version of the resource it indeed ended up with the font not being available. In our case that resulted in client system fonts getting applied, which is safer than Japanese web fonts anyway...

Comment: Good to know, more incentive to change these cache headers :)

Comment: Sure, give it a try. Oh, and another hint: note that the web is currently moving away from front awesome, since it causes massive issues with barrier reduction. SVGs appear to gain momentum for that purpose.